# Display specific category products on no results search page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

When we search for a wrong keyword like "sdfsdf" in magento site, it displays that "your search returns no results". Here I want to display any category products like "similar products" category as we display "best sellers" on home page. I have tried by calling the block in the catalogsearch.xml. BUt catalogsearch.xml doent contain any block for no results. So how can I display any category products on no results page.

I have an idea like can we display a specific category products on .phtml page? If we can display specific category of products then we can call that category from "result.phtml". Any help?

my result.phtml

```
<?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if ($this->helper('rss/catalog')->getTagFeedUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('rss/catalog')->getTagFeedUrl() ?>" class="nobr link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?></h1>
</div>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
    <p class="note-msg">
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
            <?php echo $message?><br />
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="page-title category-title">
    <h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?></h1>
</div>
<p class="note-msg">
    <?php echo ($this->getNoResultText()) ? $this->getNoResultText() : $this->__('Your search returns no results.') ?>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
        <br /><?php echo $message?>
        <?php endforeach;?>

    <?php endif; ?>
 </p>
<div class="search-noresults">
<h1>Meanwhile, You may go through our featured categories:</h1>  
</div>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->CreateBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(18)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml();?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is within catalogsearch/result.phtml template you would need to setup what happens when there are no results

```
<?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>
SHOW RESULTS
LEAVE DEFAULT
<?php else: ?>
NO RESULTS
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(4)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, BUt after adding the as you suggested, It is again showing that there are no products matching your selection. I think it is searching for the keyword in that category also.  I have upadted my result.phtml is the above question. Suggeste me.

Comment: Do you have anything in system.log or exception.log

Comment: Ok... So I've done some testing and can't find a solution around it for the moment in terms of displaying a category.

But what I would recommend is installing a free Featured Product extension, maybe one by Inchoo. I could get those results to display in the block

Comment: How do you resolve this?I am also having the same issue.@pavankumar