# Magento - How to display products below no results page?

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.8

Basically if a user searches for a product and the search returns emtpy, I want to be able to display a specific category under the text "No results matched your search".

I've tried different approaches to this, but it seems the results.phtml sorts every non-matching product from the search query string. It doesn't matter if the string matches a certain group of products - it will only display these products.

I'm trying to use a simple code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(4)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

This piece of code works anywhere on the template pages except results.phtml since the search feature blocks all non-matching products. (It will display a product if it matches the search using this code block).

Similar problem here, but no solution: [Display specific category products on no results search page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861053/display-specific-category-products-on-no-results-search-page)

Thanks, appreciate any answer to this question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom block as follows and set pagination like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664130/magento-paginate-a-custom-collection)

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourmodule/product_customlist')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

**UPDATE**

- Create Module xml file

> app/etc/modules/Custom_Products.xml

as follows

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Products>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_Products>
    </modules>
</config>
```

- Create

> app/code/local/Custom/Products/etc/config.xml

file as follows

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customproducts>
                <class>Custom_Products_Block</class>
            </customproducts>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

- Create

> app/code/local/Custom/Products/Block/Customlist.php

file as follows

```
<?php
class Custom_Products_Block_Customlist extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        // We get our collection through our model
        $this->_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
        ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price

        // Instantiate a new Pager block
        $pager = new Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager();


        // We set our limit (here an integer store in configuration).
        // /!\ The limit must be set before the collection
        $pager
        ->setLimit(5)
        ->setCollection($this->_collection);

        // Add our Pager block to our current list block
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    }

}
?>
```

- Create

> app/design/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/customlist.phtml

as follows

```
<?php    
    $_productCollection=$this->_collection;
    ...
    your products code here
    ...     

?>

<?php   
   echo $this->getChildHtml('pager');
?>
```

Check if it is working for you.

Comment: Hello Dushyant, that method would make sense, but as I'm not exactly a magento expert could you assist me through this or show me some simple steps on how to do this?